# Meteor run android-device: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: android, meteor, cors

Today, when I attempt to run my app on Android device, I am suddenly seeing:

> chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to load
>   http://192.168.178.26:3000/sockjs/info?cb=n4yqw4dcee: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:12120' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 503.", source:
>   http://localhost:12120/ (0)

and the app is unable to connect to my server.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

without any version for both Android and Meteor it is a little difficult to try to locate the issue. Meteor on Github has all these issues solved except maybe if you are using some Android 8...

Did you try to run your local server with `NODE_ENV=development meteor run android-device --settings your_settings.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was very simply that I had forgotten that I had deactivated wifi on this device.  No LAN, no server!  Six hours of hair-pulling later, all is back in order.